# How to add url params to a static url?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url

I have this address  'http://www.example.com'  I want to add 'fileName=samplefile'  url parameter to my static url (http://www.example.com).

```js
const myUrl = new URL('https://example.com);

myUrl.searchParams.append('fileName', 'samplefile');
```

I tried this approach and that didn't work.

Comment: No, it appended, try "myUrl.search".

Answer (score 0):

Just change the string in the first line and add the URL parameters as specified in the [http querystring definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

```
const myUrl = new URL('https.//example.com?fileName=samplefile');
console.log(myUrl.search);
```

Check out the [specification of URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) as well, to learn more about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of two methods: [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) & [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Example:

```
var url = new URL("https://example.com");

// If you expected result like this "http://example.com/?fileName=samplefile"
url.searchParams.append('fileName','samplefile');
console.log(url.href);//"http://example.com/?fileName=samplefile"
```

You can use [url.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/href) to get the full URL

You could also use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams)

```
let url = new URL("https://example.com");

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
urlParams.set('fileName', 'samplefile');

url.search = urlParams;
console.log(url.href);//"http://example.com/?fileName=samplefile"
```